# How to find old VPN/Remote Desktop connection settings

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, vpn

I had my computer set up before where I could connect to my work computer remotely, but in the past week I have reinstalled Windows on my machine and forgot to save the connection settings. Does anyone know if the connection settings are saved somewhere in the Windows.old folder that's left over so I can setup the connection again?

Edit: I was using the built-in Windows 7 Remote Desktop Connection.

Comment: You will need to add what VPN/RD program you where using for the best answer.

Comment: I was just using Windows Remote Desktop Connection.

Comment: A quick Google didn't turn anything up, I would go through your email or just ask your work IT dept. Or if you are at your work computer, open up a cmd prompt and type hostname, and it will print out what you need to type in.

Comment: I was afraid of that. Last time I had this set up, it was a bit of a hassle to get them to give me the right information, and I wanted to avoid that route. :/

Comment: I believe that the defaults are located in the "Documents" folder or the <user name> folder, under Remote Desktop.  It's been a while so I am really rusty, but I know it is in a folder under the <user name> called Remote Desktop.  Sorry I am at work or I would just create a connection, and tell you =D

Comment: I found what I was looking for. I'll answer this question as soon as it will let me.

Answer (score 1):

I found what I was looking for, and I'm going to put the info here.

To find my old VPN settings, I went to my old User folder, then went to `\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Network\Connections\Pbk` and opened the `rasphone.pbk` file I found there.

To find my old Remote Desktop Connection settings, it was just in my old Documents folder saved as `Default.rdp`.

Hope this is useful for anyone with my same problem in the future.